# Subview is the wrong size

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Unfortunately I'm stuck with a xib that I'm loading into scrollview and it's not behaving as I'm expecting it to.

Unless I set self.view.frame.size.height and self.view.frame.size.width, the subview is the wrong size(much too small).

Here are the values that seem to work (Horizontal mode):

**iPhone SE:**
w: 1136
h: 608
navbar: 32

**iPhone 7:**
w: 1334
h: 718
navbar: 32

**iPhone 7 Plus:**
w: 1366
h: 784
navbar: 44

**iPad 9.7":**
w: 1366
h: 980
navbar: 44

Rather than hardcoding the values, I would much rather use a way to derive those at run time. I've tried using `UIScreen.main.bounds.width/height` and `UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.width/height` but while the nativeBound works for some, the normal one seems to work for others etc.

**Main ViewController Code**

```
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height
    let screenHeightWithoutBar = screenHeight - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height



    var TopicsArray = [String](arrayLiteral: "Topic1","Topic2","Topic3","Topic4","Topic5")
    var TopicItemArray = [TopicItemViewController]()

    for i in 0..<TopicsArray.count {

        let TopicItemVC :TopicItemViewController =  TopicItemViewController(nibName: "TopicItemViewController", bundle: nil);

        TopicItemVC.toPassTopicName = TopicsArray[i]

        self.addChildViewController(TopicItemVC);
        self.scrollView!.addSubview(TopicItemVC.view);
        TopicItemVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self);

        TopicItemArray.append(TopicItemVC)  
    }

    var topicCounter = 1
    for topicView in TopicItemArray {

        if(topicCounter<TopicItemArray.count){
            var topicFrame :CGRect = screenSize;

            topicFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(topicCounter) * screenWidth;

            TopicItemArray[topicCounter].view.frame = topicFrame;
        }

        topicCounter += 1
    }

    let scrollWidth: CGFloat  = CGFloat(TopicItemArray.count) * screenWidth
    let scrollHeight: CGFloat  = screenHeightWithoutBar

    self.scrollView!.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollWidth, height: scrollHeight);
```

**TopicItemViewController code**

```
    class TopicItemViewController: UIViewController {


     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var screenScale: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.scale
        //iphone 7 plus (nav is 44)
        self.view.frame.size.height = 784
        self.view.frame.size.width = 1366

        //iphone 7   // same as resolution   
        //nav is 32
        //self.view.frame.size.height = 718 //718+32 = 750
        //self.view.frame.size.width = 1334
     }
    }
```

Comment: You dont want to use native bounds.  That is the physical pixel size of the screen, not the naturalized size.

Comment: What are you doing? Show some code where you are loading the view and trying to set its size?

Comment: @DonMag I've added the code

Comment: @Phil - you almost certainly should be using Auto-Layout and Constraints. Makes life so much easier.

Comment: @DonMag all the constraints were already in place. After moving the code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` it started working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

So after much googling and messing around, I've solved the problem.

I can indeed get rid of the hard coding as the correct values are picked up when I load it up in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead of `viewDidLoad`! All the existing constraints started working as they should. In the above example it then let me remove the `self.view.frame.size.height` and `self.view.frame.size.width`.